# Data passing with array format

Tags: jquery, cordova, slim-3, nativedroid

How to pass data in array format using jquery / slim 3

my code :

```
 $.each(data.shortlisted, function(index,element)
  {
      // alert(element.job_title);               
      $('#studentlist').append(' <a href="#" onclick="saveid('+element.job_application_id+')" class="waves-effect waves-button ui-btn waves-effect waves-button waves-effect waves-button waves-effect waves-button waves-effect waves-button">      <div class="row" style="margin:0px;color:black" >        <div class="col-xs-4">          <div class="box" style="    text-align: center;    padding-top: 14px;">            <img src="img/ment.jpg"     width= "72x"  height="72px">            </div>          </div>          <div class="col-xs-8">            <div class="box" style="padding-top: 5px">              <i class="zmdi zmdi-account"></i>              <span style="font-family: sans-serif;font-weight: bold;font-size: 15px;text-transform: capitalize;"> '+element.first_name+' '+element.last_name+' </span>              <br>                               <span >'+element.student_education+'  '+element.student_specialization+'</span>                <br>                  <span style="">            Gender </span>                  <span style="color: gray">'+element.student_gender+' </span>                  <br>                                     </div>                </div>              </div>            </a>            <hr style="margin:0">            </li> ');               
      tmpuserid.push(element.user_id);
  });
```

I need to send `tmpuserid` to slim using ajax, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Passing an array of elements via ajax:

**jQuery**

```
// Your array
var arrayOfElems = [1,2,3,4,...];

$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'path/to/handler',
  data: { arrayOfElems: JSON.stringify(arrayOfElems) },
  success: function(data) {
     // do your job with ajax response
  },
  error: function() {
     // Error handling
  }
});
```

Now, in the handler, get the request value of `arrayOfElems`, for example in c#:

**C# genericHandler (ashx.cs)**

```
var arr = context.Request["arrayOfElems"];
// Deserialize the 'arr' string into a list of numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using $.ajax method you can pass object of data by post method

```
$.ajax({
    url:"your url here",
    data:{
        userid:tmpuserid
    },
    type:'POST',
    //other AJAX option 
});
```

Now on server side you can get array in to post variable `userid`.

I hope this will be works for you.

Comment: but i cant get in array.i need to get in array in server not string